# Converting a custom date string into SQL datetime2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime2

I have to load a CSV file into a temp table in SQL server 2008. There is a column in the CSV file which contains a date string formatted like this `11/04/2017 at 08:24:52`. How can I parse this string and insert it into a `datetime2` column?

The following results in expected conversion error - `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

```
  create table #temp
  (
    date_col datetime2(2),
    some_id varchar(20)
  )

  insert into #temp(date_col , some_id )
  values ('11/04/2017 at 08:24:52', '2323434')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the `at` along with one of the spaces and then tell SQL Server which format you have your days and months in:

```
select convert(datetime2, replace('11/04/2017 at 08:24:52',' at',''),103) -- 2017-04-11 08:24:52.0000000
      ,convert(datetime2, replace('11/04/2017 at 08:24:52',' at',''),101) -- 2017-11-04 08:24:52.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks, replace seems more elegant to me than STUFF so I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stuff` to remove the `at` and [`convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) using style 103 (assuming `dd/mm/yyyy`) or 101 (assuming `mm/dd/yyyy`):

```
DECLARE @Date varchar(30) = '11/04/2017 at 08:24:52'

SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, STUFF(@Date, 12, 3, ''), 103)
```

Result:

```
    11.04.2017 08:24:52
```